# What does op-permission-level do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the new server.properties file, there is a line called `op-permission-level`, which is set to 4 by default. What does it do?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties):

> Sets permission level for ops.

Each level grants additional privileges over previous (lower levels)

1. Ops can bypass spawn protection. No commands are assigned for this level.
2. Ops can use `/clear`, `/difficulty`, `/effect`, `/gamemode`, `/gamerule`, `/give`, `/summon`, `/setblock` and `/tp`, and can edit command blocks. (Single player cheating)
3. Ops can use `/ban`, `/deop`, `/whitelist`, `/kick`, and `/op`. (Multiplayer management)
4. Ops can use `/stop`, `/save`, `/save-all`. (Server management)

4 is the highest OP level, and a level 4 operator can use all the commands from levels 1 to 3.

As said in the comments, for small servers, you probably want to your ops to be level 3.

Comment: so lvl 3 is what you want mostly, but using `stop` (which shuts down the server) can be useful if you got a ton of griefers and need to get rid of them

Comment: For small servers, ops shouldn't even need level 3 (although kick is useful).  That stuff should generally be handled by the admin anyways (which is typically an op as well).

Comment: I would personal give any op the level 3. The rest of commands the admin will use, can be done it the server panel.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but does a level 3 op have the abilities from level 1 and 2? Or do they have the abilities from 4 instead?  I want my ops to have the ability to ban and kick people, but don't want them to change gamemodes, summon, or use command blocks.

Comment: @Kenny I did some extra research, and updated the answer accordingly.