# How can I enable cheats for the players on a Minecraft Server from the console?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am running Minecraft on a linux server using a command like this:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.9.jar nogui
```

I can see how to set `gamemode` for players and `teleport` them using this console environment.

But, how do I enable cheats from the console environment so that players have these abilities too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to make players into Operators to allow them to use most commands (see [this list](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Summary_of_commands)). You can do so by running [`/op <player>`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#op) either from in game or using the server console.

This command will save these player's data within `ops.json`, found in your server directory.

Use `/deop <player>` to remove someone from the list of operators.

Comment: @ChrisGuest Make sure to check your op-level before handing it out to everyone, you may want to lower it unless you completely trust the people you're op'ing. Info about op-level here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138602/what-does-op-permission-level-do

Comment: Oh goodie, no need to restart the server!!