# How to remove /stop command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm pretty sure that this is impossible but there is a way to remove `/stop` command in a minecraft 1.11 Vanilla server?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138602/what-does-op-permission-level-do)

Comment: Some server software has different levels of OP, with the highest being able to do /stop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your server settings (`server.properties`), you can change the operator permission level. By default, the setting is 4, but changing it to 3 disables `/stop` for everyone except for the console.

Answer (score 0):

For Vanilla server, i don't think you can disable /stop command, and it is useless to disable it, as there are so many ways to stop the server when a player have the permission of using command. For example, just `/execute @e ~ ~ ~ /execute @e ~ ~ ~ /execute @e ~ ~ ~ /execute @e ~ ~ ~ /summon armor_stand` can spawn enough entities when initially there are more than 1 entity, thus 'stop' the server...
So, it is useless to disable the /stop command when the player got the permission to use command in a server.