# Can we disable only a specific command for a specific Minecraft server operator?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Lately a operator is misusing some admin commands. Is it possible for us to disable `/give` and `/gamemode` commands for him in his op.json file?

Version 1.17.1, Java Edition, server hosted from Aternos

Comment: Related: [How do I allow other players on my server to use commands like teleport, but not spawn in items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/321110/185203)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Vanilla Way

You can't. This isn't supported; you can't be an op but be unable to access these commands as `/give` and `/gamemode` belong to Level 1 (cheats) permissions; second-lowest and will lock them out of other commands.

See [What does op-permission-level do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138602/what-does-op-permission-level-do).

## Permissions Way (Requires Plugins and Bukkit/Spigot/Paper)

Give the following permission nodes and deop your player:

- `minecraft.command.clear`
- `minecraft.command.difficulty`
- `minecraft.command.effect`
- `minecraft.command.gamerule`
- `minecraft.command.summon`
- `minecraft.command.setblock`
- `minecraft.command.tp`
- `minecraft.command.ban`
- `minecraft.command.deop`
- `minecraft.command.whitelist`
- `minecraft.command.kick`
- `minecraft.command.op`
- `minecraft.command.stop`
- `minecraft.command.save`
- `minecraft.command.save-all`

Also, you shouldn't be giving away op to players you don't want cheating. That's on *you*; just `/deop` them. By giving all operator powers other than `/give` or `/gamemode`, what's stopping them from them just `/ban`ing you out of retaliation?